# Join table from values nested deeply in a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, json

In Postgres 12.3 I am having trouble building the correct SQL query that can join a table from a deeply nested array in a jsonb object with rows from another table.

The deeply nested array contains strings and optionally an array of strings. These arrays should be flattened and then used to join in the other table.

Here is a DB Fiddle with the below data ready to test:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6tMMNn3JsgkbehCptw4xEx/0

### Details

I need a SQL query given the below tables that will return from `order_batches` the batches which contain orders where state does not equal 'picked' or 'packed'. With the given table data below only `order_batches` with ID `1` should be returned.

Essentially I need the query to look at each row in `order_batches`, for all the `tags->'bins'` arrays, find and flatten any `order_numbers`, and join (or sub-select?) the `orders` table on those `order_numbers`. The where clause should retrieve only those batches that include an order with a state that does not match 'picked' or 'packed'.

Expressing this in pseudo sql might look like:

```
SELECT order_batches.*
FROM order_batches
JOIN orders ON order_batches.tags->'bins'->__all array elements__->'order_numbers' = orders.number
WHERE orders.state IS NOT IN ('picked', 'packed')
```

### Desired Output

The output that I am looking for is equal to the result of this query:

```
SELECT * from order_numbers WHERE id = 1
```

```
╔════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║                                                             tags                                                             ║
╠════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ {"bins":[{"order_numbers":["555111111","555111112",["555111114","555111115"]]},{"order_numbers":["555111116","555111117"]}]} ║
╚════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

### Resources

I have tried searching for an answer, but did not find one exactly like mine. These results have helped, but I'm still not sure how to get it right:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766873/how-to-join-on-the-values-returned-from-json-array-elements-in-postgresql
- [PostgreSql : flatten json array data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125912/postgresql-flatten-json-array-data)

### Test Data

Here is the db schema and test data:

```
create table "order_batches" (id bigint primary key, tags jsonb);
insert into "order_batches" 
  (id, tags)
values 
  (1, '{
  "bins": [
    {
      "order_numbers": [
        "555111111",
        "555111112",
        [
          "555111114",
          "555111115"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "order_numbers": [
        "555111116",
        "555111117"
      ]
    }
  ]
}'),
(2, '{
  "bins": [
    {
      "order_numbers": [
        "555111118",
        "111111111"
            ]
        }
  ]
}');

create table "orders" (id bigint primary key, "number" varchar(255), state varchar(255));
INSERT INTO "orders" (id, "number", state) VALUES
(1, '555111111', 'picked'),
(2, '555111112', 'picked'),
(3, '555111114', 'picked'),
(4, '555111115', 'ready'),
(5, '555111116', 'ready'),
(6, '555111117', 'ready'),
(7, '555111118', 'picked'),
(8, '111111111', 'packed');
```

### Attempts

Here are some queries I have tried in my attempt to get it working and to understand the problem better:

```
SELECT ob.id, j.nums->'order_numbers'
FROM order_batches ob
CROSS JOIN lateral jsonb_array_elements(tags->'bins') j(nums)
JOIN orders o on o.number = j.nums->'order_numbers'
```

```
WITH numbers AS(
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements("tags"->'bins') AS numbers FROM order_batches
)
SELECT * FROM numbers JOIN orders o ON o.number = numbers.numbers
```

```
SELECT 
case jsonb_typeof(numbers)
    when 'string' then numbers->>0
    when 'array' then jsonb_array_elements_text(numbers)
end as number
FROM order_batches, jsonb_array_elements(order_batches.tags->'bins') as numbers
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this problem. At this point I do not think it would be worth revising the data structure. I'm hoping a SQL expert can whip up some magic to help me (and others) out here.

Comment: Do you really have a nested array inside the `order_numbers` array (id = 1 in the sample data). That looks like a really ugly way of storing things. It would be way easier if all elements of the `order_numbers` array were always the same type

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Postgres 11.4, sorry I thought I mentioned that, but I will edit it. The nested array inside `order_numbers` is ugly, but it does serve a purpose in our system. This allows us to group orders together that are being shipped to the same location, ensuring they end up together. There is probably a better way to model that, but that is why it is. I will edit to show desired output, basically `SELECT * from order_batches where id = 1` is equivalent to the desired output (given this dataset). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Roger that @a_horse_with_no_name. I could store the simple array of `order_numbers` in a second key on that jsonb object. I will revise the question. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks so much @a_horse_with_no_name. I have no problem upgrading to PostgreSQL 12. I'll update my question. If you'd like to submit your example as an answer that definitely solves it for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy to solve in Postgres 12, because the new SQL JSON/Path feature does the heavy lifting of iterating through (nested) arrays.

```
SELECT ob.*
FROM  order_batches ob
where exists (select *
              from orders ord
              where jsonb_path_exists(ob.tags, '$.bins[*].order_numbers[*] ? (@ == $nr)', jsonb_build_object('nr', ord.number))
              and ord.state NOT IN ('picked', 'packed'));
```

The JSON path expression `'$.bins[*].order_numbers[*]` iterates through all array elements in the `order_numbers` array - including nested arrays. The `jsonb_path_exists()` then checks if there is a match with the `number` from the `orders` table.

The number is passed as a "json parameter" to the `jsonb_path_exists()` function and the `$nr` placeholder references that. The name of that parameter must match the key of the JSON value passed as the third parameter of the `jsonb_path_exists` function.

I don't think this is going to be very fast though as the way the `jsonb_path_exists()` function is used, can't make use of an index as far as I know.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2f578186e95cafa4cf87d41b57a85319)